# Prepare Soap service with SAML assertion in .net

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, saml, soapcore

I must implemented SOAP Web Service but i don't have a lot experience in this job.
I read something about WCF, SoapCore etc. and tried to create some solutions.
What I need to implement:

1. Service which get request with SAML token in header (wsse:security).
2. After receiving request I must forward SAML token with elements from soap:body to verification services.
3. If I get allow to share data with request actor. I must generate response with some data from database.

My tech stack is .net vb/c#.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the demo first according to the official documentation: [SAML Token Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/saml-token-provider). This sample demonstrates how to implement a custom client SAML token provider. A token provider in Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is used for supplying credentials to the security infrastructure.

Comment: But i dont need to provide token.  Token are shared by Secure Token Service (STS) witch is element of another system. 
Client sending request to my service with this SAML token, i get this message and forward token to STS for verification. If verification passed i reply to client with data. My problem is to catch SAML token and forward it to STS in WCF Service Application

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276023/using-tokens-assigned-from-an-sts-to-call-a-wcf-service

Comment: @Daxter44 did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, and i gave up with this